# Angular JS: Pass a forms select option value to database not working

Tags: angularjs

I currently have a form with a `<select>` and options as below. I am trying to pass the values into my db, but when running the app category is coming out as undefined. The form is using ng-controller="eventCtrl"

Form Select Code Below.

```
<div class="input-field col s5">
 <select class="browser-default">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your category</option>
  <option value="Mountain" ng-model="category">Mountain</option>
  <option value="Forest" ng-model="category">Forest</option>
  <option value="Beach & Sea" ng-model="category">Beach & Sea</option>
  <option value="Fresh Water" ng-model="category">Fresh Water</option>
  <option value="Aero" ng-model="category">Aero</option>
  <option value="Desert" ng-model="category">Desert</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

eventCtrl Code Below.

```
angular.module('socialApp')
 .controller('eventCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.createEvent = function() {
   $http.post('/events/createEvent', {
    title: $scope.title,
    category: $scope.category,
    city: $scope.city,
    state: $scope.state,
    date: $scope.date,
    time: $scope.time,
    description: $scope.description
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.data.status);
    console.log(result);
  })
 };
});
```

I am so lost with this please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ng-model` attribute should be on the `select` element instead of each `option` element as so:

```
<div class="input-field col s5">
 <select class="browser-default" ng-model="category">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your category</option>
  <option value="Mountain">Mountain</option>
  <option value="Forest">Forest</option>
  <option value="Beach & Sea">Beach & Sea</option>
  <option value="Fresh Water">Fresh Water</option>
  <option value="Aero">Aero</option>
  <option value="Desert">Desert</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

I'd definitely look up the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) on this as it's very detailed!

Comment: Also, consider using the `ngOptions` directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Yes the `ngOptions` directive is very good to consider. Personally I use static HTML lists with angular if it is a) a long list and b) is not going to change. This is because `ng-options` and `ng-repeat` can have performance issues with very long lists!

Comment: @donghoonkim, if this or any other future answer solves your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @papakia - as you can tell, I am still a noob when it comes to stack. Thanks for helping out with this issue, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ngOptions like this:

```
<select ng-model="category" 
        ng-options="obj as obj.name for obj in arrayOfObject" />
```

> The a as b syntax lets you bind a to the model, while showing b for your dropdown label.

If in case you need to get the value on change use `ng-change="getSelectedValue(category)"`